# Poner un mensaje de error en aserción de JUnit al trabajar con Optional

Tags: java-8, junit, optional

Actualmente tengo mi código así:

```
@Test
public void validateSomething() {
  Optional<String> mensajeDeError = validador.validar(null);
  assertFalse(mensajeDeError.isPresent());
}
```

Quisiera poner un mensaje de texto que imprima el valor de mi mensaje de error cuando este exista pero si intento

```
@Test
public void validateSomething() {
  Optional<String> mensajeDeError = validador.validar(null);
  assertFalse("no debía de haber errores, pero el validador regresó el siguiente mensaje de error: "+mensajeDeError.get(),mensajeDeError.isPresent());
}
```

me marca error cuando el mensaje de error no existe.

> java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present
>
> at java.util.Optional.get(Optional.java:135)

¿Alguna recomendación?

Answer (score -1):

[get()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#get--) te retorna el valor si está presente, en caso contrario arroja una excepcion **NoSuchElementException**.

En la siguiente línea estás llamando a dicho método sobre un Optional que no tiene valor, por eso te arroja la excepción.

```
assertFalse("no debía de haber errores, pero el validador regresó el siguiente mensaje de error: "+mensajeDeError.get(),mensajeDeError.isPresent());
```

En todo caso deberías asignar un string al método validar(string):

```
Optional<String> mensajeDeError = validador.validar("mensaje esperado");
```

**En resumen**:

- Si el objeto Optional no contiene valor, `isPresent()` retorna `false` y `get()` arroja la excepción `NoSuchElementException`.
- Si el objeto Opcional contiene valor, `isPresent()`retorna `true` y `get()` retorna el valor que contiene el objeto.

Comment: la prueba es que no falle mandando un null al validador, ponerle un valor de cadena va contra la intención de la prueba unitaria

Comment: Entonces el método validar está retornando un Optional sin valor, por eso estás obteniendo esa excepción..... `isPresent()` te va a retornar `false`, pero `get()` te arroja la excepción. En todo caso deberías cambiar el mensaje del test sin incluir el resultado de `get()`

Comment: si no incluyo el resultado de get no sabré que mensaje de error mandó y deberé depurar para conocerlo, cuando en teoría debería de poderlo conocer desde la prueba unitaria. ( y eso si es posible si en vez de usar el optional usara null )

Comment: Quita `+mensajeDeError.get()` y fijate que te muestra mensaje. Ahí te das cuenta que no había mensaje de error y la variable está lanzando excepción al llamar al método `get`

Comment: Sé usar optional y sé por qué me arroja el error, lo que pregunto es otra cosa, deberías de leer la pregunta bien.

Comment: Daaaaale, voy a comenzar a leer mejor las preguntas y dejar de remarcarte que tu error está en como interpretas el método `get` de `Optional`. Espero que alguien te pueda ayudar... Saludos.

Comment: Lo resolví así: http://javapro.org/castellano/2019/04/24/java-optional/